# Google Play asks to remove Install_referrer from affected apps

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, dependencies

Google Play asks to remove Install_referrer from affected apps, but the apps don't have install_referrer in the Manifest. What should I do?

Comment: add your gradle dependencies to the question, it's probably from an SDK that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found the solution. I have libraries which are using the install_referrer:
- firebase
- facebook

Facebook and Firebase did not update the SDK yet, hopefully they will provide a new version of SDK soon.